# How do I insert a line at a specific row in multiple files on Unix?

Tags: perl, unix, sed

I need to insert a line with specific text on the second line (thus moving the other lines down in the file) of hundreds of files in a directory. Any quick Unix tips on how that can be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '2iYour line here' /dir/*
```

Note that `sed -i` semantics vary by Unix flavor, so check your `man sed`.  This is written for the GNU flavor.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pi -we'print "extra line\n" if $. == 3; close ARGV if eof' files
```

The `close(ARGV)` is necessary to restart the line counter `$.` at the beginning of each file; by default, it counts lines across files.

Comment: Don't you think it's worth doing `-i.bak` to protect you from a typo wiping out quite a lot of data? (Just imagine you forget `-p`.)

Comment: @Telemachus: when doing a whole directory, I prefer to copy the whole directory first (e.g. cp -a dir{,.save}); then I can mv it back if needed.

Answer (score 1):

this is an `AWK` use rather than the `sed`,

```
for i in $(<list_of_files)
do
     awk '{if (FNR!=2) print $0; 
           else { print "new line"; print $0}}' $i > ${i}.tmp;
     mv ${i}.tmp $i;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | xargs --replace=foo perl -i -ne 'print; print "second line text\n" unless $x++;' foo
```

Comment: I vote *never* to recommend `perl -i` without a backup: `perl -i.bak`. It's easy, and you can easily remove the backups once you're sure you didn't get your edit wrong.